# How to use ngIf in html comments?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

What I'm trying to do is the following:

```
<!-- directive: ng-my-if condition -->
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="myStyle1.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="myStyle2.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="myStyle3.css">
<!-- end ng-my-if -->
```

I tried to build my own `ngIf` but didn't work.
Is there a way to achieve this idea ?
Why to use html comments? because the styles will be in `<head>` tag which doesn't allow `<div>` or other tags to be used to add `ngIf` in it, and also because those `myStyle1.css, myStyle2.css, myStyle3.css` will be compressed into one `.css` file using `gulp` task with `useref` plugin, so I can't add `ng-if` for each style tag.
Also can't put `link` tags inside `body` and wrap them with `div` coz there's `link` tags up in the `<head>` tags and I need to respect the order of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AngularJS` has a restriction to use `ng-if` only with `attribute` by `A` as something like below. so, you can't use this in `comment`

```
var ngIfDirective = ['$animate', function($animate) {
  return {
    transclude: 'element',
    priority: 600,
    terminal: true,
    restrict: 'A',
```

Instead you can create a custome directive with restrict `M` as below. The current directive I have written below will work for one comment per one element. If you need to handle multiple element, the directive should be extended.

**Note**: I have used the `div` below only to show/hide the value as `link` don't have any display

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('TestController', function($scope){
  $scope.checked = true;
});

app.directive('ngIfExt', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'M',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngIfExt, function(value, oldValue) {
            if(value) {
              if(attrs.target){
                 $(element).after(attrs.target);
               }
            } else {
                var targetElement = $(element).next().clone();
                attrs.target = targetElement;
                $(element).next().remove();
            }
        }, true);
    }};
});

angular.bootstrap(document, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="TestController">
  <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checked"/> Show/hide
  <!-- directive: ng-if-ext checked -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="myStyle1.css">
  <!-- directive: ng-if-ext checked -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="myStyle2.css">
  <!-- directive: ng-if-ext checked -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" ng-href="myStyle3.css">
  <!-- directive: ng-if-ext checked -->
  <div>Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: As I mentioned I can't use `ng-if` on `link` it self coz those `.css` gonna be compressed and converted into one `link` tag, so all attributes will be removed.